# Error in HTML display of <legend> tag

Tags: html

I have a bit of code something like the below:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form Title</legend>
        <legend>Text Box 1</legend>
            <input type="text"/>
        <legend>Text Box 2</legend>
            <input type="text"/>
        <legend>Text Box 3</legend>
            <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Nevermind that the above snippet is incomplete, it will serve as an example for my problem.

When the page is displayed, about half of the time it loads as the left bit of the image below, whereas the rest of the time it loads as intended like the right bit.

[image: htmldisplaybit]

Why is this? I know `<legend>` is being used improperly here, and I plan to replace them with `<label>` tags instead. I'm gradually replacing all of the errors I was taught in university, but old habits die hard. Is this perhaps the issue?

The source code for the page when either appears is identical to each other.

Comment: Well, as you said, the legend tag is being used improperly. The way you're using it doesn't make sense and its behavior is undefined. Use a label tag for the inputs, as you should.

Comment: @Josh, yes, I have full intentions of correcting my improper use of `<legend>`; my question was more to do with if that was the issue or if it was something else. This error does not appear on my local machine using wamp, but it does on my web host. While I plan to fix my tags, I'd like to know that's the solution before I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, don't use `<legend>` like that. That's not what it's for, it's wrong, and if it renders correctly, it's purely by chance.

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtan5/) for a proper implementation.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Send Support Inquiry</legend>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="30" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label, input, textarea
{
    float: left;    
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What if I have two text fields? Say I split a name field into first name and last name, `<label>` can only be used for strictly one input. Here's an example: http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/4523/bz81.png For some fields I have multiple inputs.

Comment: In the first you'd say `for="first_name"` and your input would be `id="first_name"`, etc. The `for="blah"` param is arbitrary, and is just used to line it up with a certain input ID.

Comment: Thank you. It's nice to know some people will help and not just drone in on the beginner with downvotes. Your explanation was perfect.

Comment: @riista: Not a problem, glad to help. I'd say in the future, just stick with what is right, and then try to debug. You're working against yourself trying to fix something that you at least partly know the cause of.